# Reshape each row of a data.frame to be a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I am working with the hand-written zip codes dataset. I have loaded the dataset like this:

```
digits <- read.table("./zip.train",
                     quote            = "",
                     comment.char     = "",
                     stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Then I get only the ones:

```
ones <- digits[digits$V1 == 1, -1]
```

Right now, in `ones` I have 442 rows, with 256 column. I need to transform each row in `ones` to a 16x16 `matrix`. I think what I am looking for is a list of 16x16 matrix like the ones in this question:

[How to create a list of matrix in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13765144/how-to-create-a-list-of-matrix-in-r)

But I tried with my data and did not work.

At first I tried `ones <- apply(ones, 1, matrix, nrow = 16, ncol = 16)` but is not working as I thought it was. I also tried `lapply` with no luck.

Comment: Sample data and desired output would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

though there are probably simple ways, you can try with `lapply`:

```
ones_matrix <- lapply(1:nrow(ones), function(i){matrix(ones[i, ], nrow=16)})
```

Comment: Args!, thank you so much, I've been trying for hours. I would never had think of a solution like this.

Comment: :-) you're welcome glad that it helped "unstuck" you  :-)

Answer (score 4):

An alternative is to just change the `dim`s of your matrix.

Consider the following matrix "M":

```
M <- matrix(1:12, ncol = 4)
M
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    4    7   10
# [2,]    2    5    8   11
# [3,]    3    6    9   12
```

We are looking to create a three dimensional array from this, so you can specify the dimensions as "row", "column", "third-dimension". However, since the matrix is constructed by column, you first need to `t`ranspose it before changing the dimensions.

```
`dim<-`(t(M), c(2, 2, nrow(M)))
# , , 1
# 
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    7
# [2,]    4   10
# 
# , , 2
# 
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    2    8
# [2,]    5   11
# 
# , , 3
# 
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    3    9
# [2,]    6   12
```

Comment: nice alternative to a list, smarter way :-)